# AngularJS change date on http get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I'm doing a HTTP get request, in my AngularJS controller, but I don't know why, my date in my Model is different from the date in the Query String generated:

```
$scope.modalSave = function() {
  console.log("modalSave:", $scope.modal);
  // prints the correct date: 2015-10-16 00:00

  $http.get('/Planner/Save', {
    params: {
      id: $scope.modal.Id,
      date: $scope.modal.Date //wrong date: 2015-10-15 23:00
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Make [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example...

Comment: try `console.log("modalSave:", $scope.modal.Date);` are you get same result?

Comment: console.log("modalSave:", $scope.modal) prints the correct date: 2015-10-16 00:00

Comment: @SarjanDesai, I could do a jsfiddle example, but I had this on Azure working correctly and the problem appear when I change to a new host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typical UTC date problem. The server on which the server is could have a different date set so it is returning a "wrong" values. I would double check the date on the service side.

Comment: I agree, but I don't understand why when I do 'new Date()' I get the right date, but when I pass it to ajax request, it changes it